# GridBagLayOut spanning columns upward?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Can i span the button upward or backward in GridBagLayout ? 
Here,  button five height is 2 and width is 1 ,but it doesn't work. there is a space left upwards , this is where i want button five to span upwards.

```
public class GridBag2 extends JPanel
{
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    public static void main (String args [])
    {
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("GridBag2 Span R&C");
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(fr.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setSize(600,600);
        fr.add(new GridBag2());
        fr.setVisible(true);

    }

    GridBag2()
    {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        constraints.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        addGB(new JButton("one"),0,0,1.0,1.0,1,1);
        addGB(new JButton("two"),1,0,1.0,1.0,1,1);
        addGB(new JButton("three"),2,0,1.0,1.0,1,1);
        addGB(new JButton("four"),1,1,1,1,1,2); //spans 2 rows
        addGB(new JButton("five"),0,2,1,1,2,1); //spans 2 columns

    }

    void addGB(Component comp,int gx, int gy, double wx, double wy, int h, int w)
    {
        constraints.gridx=gx;
        constraints.gridy=gy;
        constraints.weightx=wx;
        constraints.weighty=wy;
        constraints.gridheight=h;
        constraints.gridwidth=w;
        this.add(comp,constraints);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post up your expected result as a pic?

Comment: `gridWidth` and `gridHeight` span left/down respectively...

Comment: i don;t have enough reputation to post pic

Comment: i even tried to place the button five beside button four and span the columns downward,like addGB(new JButton("five"),0,1,1,1,2,1);

Comment: This is tricky.  You need to understand that if the row/column that the component is moving into contains no other components, those row/columns effectively don't exists

Comment: i solved it by adding empty comp,  addGB(new JButton("five"),0,1,1,1,2,1);
        addGB(new JLabel(),1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1); //spans 2 rows thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

Based on you comments, the coordinates you are passing your factory method don't make sense...

```
addGB(new JButton("four"),1,1,1,1,1,2); //spans 2 rows
addGB(new JButton("five"),0,2,1,1,2,1); //spans 2 columns
```

Basically you're saying you want to span 2 rows, then span 2 columns, but the parameters are the wrong way round...

```
addGB(new JButton("four"),1,1,1,1,2,1); //spans 2 rows
addGB(new JButton("five"),0,2,1,1,1,2); //spans 2 columns
```

Would result in what your comments are asking, for example...

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GridBag2 extends JPanel {

    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("GridBag2 Span R&C");
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(fr.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setSize(600, 600);
        fr.add(new GridBag2());
        fr.setVisible(true);

    }

    GridBag2() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        addGB(new JButton("one"), 0, 0, 1.0, 1.0, 1, 1);
        addGB(new JButton("two"), 1, 0, 1.0, 1.0, 1, 1);
        addGB(new JButton("three"), 2, 0, 1.0, 1.0, 1, 1);
        addGB(new JButton("four"), 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1); //spans 2 rows
        addGB(new JButton("five"), 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2); //spans 2 columns

    }

    void addGB(Component comp, int gx, int gy, double wx, double wy, int h, int w) {
        constraints.gridx = gx;
        constraints.gridy = gy;
        constraints.weightx = wx;
        constraints.weighty = wy;
        constraints.gridheight = h;
        constraints.gridwidth = w;
        this.add(comp, constraints);
    }
}
```

But, wait, what happened to the second/third rows?  The second row was collapsed as basically, it no longer contained anything (that could be used to calculate a viable height)

You can get around this by using a "empty" component which will help it make decisions...

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GridBag2 extends JPanel {

    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("GridBag2 Span R&C");
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(fr.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setSize(600, 600);
        fr.add(new GridBag2());
        fr.setVisible(true);

    }

    GridBag2() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        addGB(new JButton("one"), 0, 0, 1.0, 1.0, 1, 1);
        addGB(new JButton("two"), 1, 0, 1.0, 1.0, 1, 1);
        addGB(new JButton("three"), 2, 0, 1.0, 1.0, 1, 1);
        addGB(new JLabel(), 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1); //spans 2 rows
        addGB(new JButton("four"), 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1); //spans 2 rows
        addGB(new JButton("five"), 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2); //spans 2 columns

    }

    void addGB(Component comp, int gx, int gy, double wx, double wy, int h, int w) {
        constraints.gridx = gx;
        constraints.gridy = gy;
        constraints.weightx = wx;
        constraints.weighty = wy;
        constraints.gridheight = h;
        constraints.gridwidth = w;
        this.add(comp, constraints);
    }
}
```